# translate letters to numbers using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, decoding

What I have:

```
s='areyo uanap ppple'
```

What I want:

```
s='12345 12324 11123'
```

Should I use dictionary and translate each `i` in `s.split(' ')`? or is there a simpler method?

Comment: I'm not seeing this mapping.  You first translate `a` to `1` (in the first word) then later you traslate `a` to `2` (second word)...

Comment: I think OP is starting afresh for each word.

Comment: Please define the letters to numbers mapping.

Answer (score 2):

```
s='areyo uanap ppple'
incr=1
out=''
dict={}
for x in s:
    if ' ' in x:
        incr=1
        dict={}
        out+=' '
        continue;
    if x in dict.keys():
        out+=str(dict[x])
        continue;

    out+=str(incr)
    dict[x]=incr
    incr=incr+1

print out //12345 12324 11123
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand the OP correctly, this might be a solution:

```
s='areyo uanap ppple'
def trans(word):
    d = {}
    for char in word:
        if char not in d.keys():
            d[char] = len(d.keys()) + 1
        yield str(d[char])
o = ' '.join([  ''.join(trans(word)) for word in s.split(' ')])
print repr(o)
```

which results in:

```
'12345 12324 11123'
```

building on the `unique` of unutbu answer, this would also be possible:

```
' '.join([''.join([ { a:str(i+1) for i,a in enumerate(unique(word)) }[char] for char in word]) for word in s.split(' ') ])
```

here is another one, i think i got a little carried away :)

```
' '.join([ w.translate(maketrans(*[ ''.join(x) for x in zip(*[ (a,str(i+1)) for i,a in enumerate(unique(w)) ]) ])) for w in s.split(' ') ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [unicode.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import string

def unique(seq): 
    # http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark (Dave Kirby)
    # Order preserving
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

def word2num(word):
    uniqs = unique(word)
    assert len(uniqs) < 10
    d = dict(zip(map(ord,uniqs),
                 map(unicode,string.digits[1:])))
    return word.translate(d)

s = u'areyo uanap ppple'
for word in s.split():
    print(word2num(word))
```

yields

```
12345
12324
11123
```

Note that it is unclear what you want to happen if there are more than 9 unique letters in a word. I've used an `assert` to complain if `word2num` is passed such a word.

Comment: there will not be more than 5 unique letters in a word, since each 5 letters are considered independently. string like 'abcde fghij ffabc' will be translated as '12345 12345 11234'

Answer (score 1):

using `unique_everseen()` from [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
In [5]: def func(s):
    for x in s.split():
            dic={}
            for i,y in enumerate(unique_everseen(x)):
                     dic[y]=dic.get(y,i+1)
            yield "".join(str(dic[k]) for k in x)    
            dic={}
   ...:             

In [6]: " ".join(x for x in func('areyo uanap ppple'))
Out[6]: '12345 12324 11123'

In [7]: " ".join(x for x in func('abcde fghij ffabc'))
Out[7]: '12345 12345 11234'
```