# Variables inside a function not recreated at each function call

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, python-2.7

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498882/translate-letters-to-numbers-using-python), to which my solution was the following (I didn't post this answer):

```
def wordigit(w):
    digits = {}
    c = itertools.count(1)
    for char in w:
        if w not in digits:
            digits[char] = c.next()
    return ''.join(str(i) for i in (digits[char] for char in w))

print ' '.join(wordigit(w) for w in s.split())
```

At first glance, this looks right. But I got an erroneous result:

```
In [236]: ' '.join(wordigit(w) for w in s.split())
Out[236]: '12345 14345 33345' # notice the numbers in the second "word". 1-4 is not a legal progression for itertools.count. It should have been 12324 instead of 14345
```

I had developed this solution in IPython. Thinking that this might be a bug with some optimization that IPython does under the hood, I fired up a python interpreter to see what it said. I also thought that the list-comprehension might be leading to some anomalous behaviour. So I tried calling `wordigit` twice - once on each of two unequal strings and got the following results:

```
>>> def wordigit(w):
...     digits = {}
...     c = itertools.count(1)
...     for char in w:
...         if w not in digits:
...             digits[char] = c.next()
...     return ''.join(str(i) for i in (digits[char] for char in w))
... 
>>> wordigit('areyo')
'12345'
>>> wordigit('uanap')
'14345'
```

So it seems that even though I create the `itertools.count` object within the function (and therefore the function should recreate it at every run), it somehow persists after the function has returned and gets reused without re-initialization when the function is called again. Similarly, It is clear that this is the case for the `dict` "digits" in `wordigit` as well.

How is this happening? Somehow, this behavior doesn't make sense to me.

I notice this behavior with Python 2.7.1 in Ipython and a fresh Python 2.7.3 interpreter

Comment: off-topic: prefer using `next(c)` instead of `c.next()`, as `next(c)` will work on both python 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I agree, but will point out that `next()` as a builtin wasn't until 2.6 so you're out of luck if using 2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't look right:

```
for char in w:
    if w not in digits:
      ^^^
```

Maybe:

```
for char in w:
    if char not in digits: 
       ^^^^
```